# Angular template not loading / routes

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs

I'm learning angular and i'm having an issue with displaying my partial.
It's probably something trivial that i forgot but i can't seem to find it.

index.html

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html ng-app="myTool">
     <head>
     <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/css/bootstrap.min.css" />
     <script type="text/javascript" src="http://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular.js/1.4.5/angular.min.js"></script>
     <script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular.js/1.4.5/angular-route.js"></script>
      <script type="text/javascript" src="app.js"></script>
     <script type="text/javascript" src="tool-controller.js"></script>
     </head>

    <body>
    <div class="container">
      <nav class="navbar navbar-default">
        <div class="container-fluid">
          <div class="navbar-header">
            <a class="navbar-brand" href="#"><img alt="myTool" src="/templogo.png"></a>
          </div>
          <div id="navbar" class="navbar-collapse collapse">
            <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
            <li><a ng-href="#/dashboard">DashBoard</a></li>
            <li><a ng-href="#/new">New</a></li>
            </ul>
            <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
            <li><a ng-href="#">Logout </a> </li>
            </ul>
          </div>
        </div>
      </nav>
    <div ng-view>
    </div>
    </div>

    </body>
    </html>
```

app.js

```
    angular.module('myTool',['ngRoute'])
    .config(function($routeProvider){
      $routeProvider.when('/new', {
       templateUrl: '/tool-new.html',
        controller:'ToolController',
        controllerAs: "tool"
      })
      .when('/dashboard', {
       templateUrl: '/empty.html'
      })
      .when('/', {
      templateUrl: '/index.html'
      })
      .otherwise({ redirectTo: '/' });
    });
```

tool-controller.js

```
    angular.module('myTool', [])
    .controller('ToolController',['$scope', function($scope) {
      $scope.list = [];
      $scope.tool = {};
      $scope.submit = function() {
              $scope.list.push(this.tool);
              $scope.succes = 'sent';
          };
      $scope.search = function() {
        };
    }]);
```

and my partial are in tool-new.html and empty.html.

I don't really see what i'm missing :

-index.html as layout with ng-view as placeholder for my partial

- basic routes + fall back
- my controller linked to my template
- html files as my templates with random stuff inside.
- im running everything on a local webserv

I've tried adding the controller as a dependency as written in the angulardoc , i've also tried specifically calling the templates in script tags in between my ng-show tags.

Thanks for the suggestions.

Comment: Are the files index.html and empty.html inside any folder? Because you have `templateUrl: '/empty.html'` with a slash in front of it. Also check your console to see if you have any errors, and you can try `<div ng-view=""></div>`

Comment: no everything is in the same folder for now , i've tried both /'empty' and 'empty' and it's not working :(.
I have no error in the console

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try adding your views like this(just remove '/' at the beginning of the view name):

```
angular.module('myTool',['ngRoute'])
.config(function($routeProvider){
  $routeProvider.when('/new', {
   templateUrl: 'tool-new.html',
    controller:'ToolController',
    controllerAs: "tool"
  })
  .when('/dashboard', {
   templateUrl: 'empty.html'
  })
  .when('/', {
  templateUrl: 'index.html'
  })
  .otherwise({ redirectTo: '/' });
});
```

And also remove [] from **tool-controller.js**

```
angular.module('myTool')
.controller('ToolController',['$scope', function($scope) {
  $scope.list = [];
  $scope.tool = {};
  $scope.submit = function() {
          $scope.list.push(this.tool);
          $scope.succes = 'sent';
      };
  $scope.search = function() {
    };
}]);
```

Comment: Man, see my updated answer.It works!Please check it and answer me.

Comment: ok it does work Thanks alot dude. i've removed the [] and it fixed it. Can you explain me why ? is it resetting my dependency ? I saw that in a tutorial i thought it was a convention to leave it empty..

Comment: You need to declare your dependency only once. at the beginning of the app.js.Personally I would recommend you to do something like that

var app = angular.module('myTool',['ngRoute']);

...
//in another file
app.controller(....)

Answer (score 0):

You are missing the name of the controller in the html i.e. toolController also switch to javascript naming convention of your files it will become easier for you to code.Your actual code in the html should have ng-controller="toolController" which should be placed on your div tag in order to load the controller.

Comment: it's there , in my new.html : `<form ng-controller="ToolController as tool" ng-submit="submit()">`

Comment: It won't work there in order to load the partial you have to tell the html which controller has your content for ng-view your body tag or your div tag in the index.html has to contain the ng-controller to load tool-new.html